# My react-native TextInput disappear when I start typing

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-native-ui-component

I have screen named EditScreen. It has text input that takes the height of the device.
The problem is that when I start typing the text goes above and disappear.
Any solutions, please.

**here is my Text Input component**

```
 <View style={styles.InputContainer}>
      <ScrollView>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.inputText}
          placeholder={"Take Notes ..."}
          onChangeText={HandlingTextValut}
          value={notes}
          multiline={true}
        />
      </ScrollView>
    </View>

// and here is its styles
InputContainer: {
    flex:1,
  },
  inputText: {
    paddingBottom: Dimensions.get("window").height- 100,
    paddingLeft: 10,
    paddingRight: 10,
    fontSize: 20,
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

can you please try these props `numberOfLines` and `onContentSizeChange` .

Reference link : https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#numberoflines

Answer (score 0):

remove `paddingBottom: Dimensions.get("window").height- 100,` from input style